# I have a function but i can not create a form using it

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

This is my code

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <script>
    function year(n) {
    var a = 4;
    var k = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        k += 1;
        if (k % 4 == 0) {
            a += 2;
        } else {
            a += 1;
        }
    }
    if (a % 7 == 1) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 6");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 3, thang 11");
        }
    } else if (a % 7 == 2) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 2, thang 3, thang 11");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 2, thang 8");
        }
    } else if (a % 7 == 3) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 8");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 5");
        }
    } else if (a % 7 == 4) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 5");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 10");
        }
    } else if (a % 7 == 5) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 1, thang 10");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 1, thang 4");
        }
    } else if (a % 7 == 6) {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 4, thang 7");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 9, thang 12");
        }
    } else {
        if (n % 4 != 0) {
            document.write("thang 9, thang 12");
        } else {
            document.write("thang 6");
        }
    }
}
year(1998);

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Sorry for my ugly code, this function will show the months which include the "Friday 13th" after you enter the value of year.

Example: The year 1998 has three satisfied months: Feb, Mar and Nov.

But I want to create a form for the post on my wordpress page, inwhich people can type the number of year in the input box, click the button "Show", then get the result in the output box.

Hope that i'll get the support for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any sort of form on your wordpress blog, including the code you've posted here.

One way to do this would be to create a page template for this form, and then create a page on your wordpress blog that uses this template. Creating a template will allow you to specify any PHP, HTML and CSS you like.

You can find more information on page templates here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id='year' type='text' />
<button onclick='javascript:year()'>Submit</button>
<div id='res' style='width:100%;height:200px'></div>
<script>
    function year() {
        var n=document.getElementById('year').value,
        out=document.getElementById('res'),
        a = 4,
        k = 1;

        out.innerHTML="";
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            k += 1;
            if (k % 4 == 0) {
                a += 2;
            } else {
                a += 1;
            }
        }
        if (a % 7 == 1) {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 6";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 3, thang 11";
            }
        } else if (a % 7 == 2) {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 2, thang 3, thang 11";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 2, thang 8";
            }
        } else if (a % 7 == 3) {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 8";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 5";
            }
        } else if (a % 7 == 4) {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 5";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 10";
            }
        } else if (a % 7 == 5) {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 1, thang 10";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 1, thang 4";
            }
        } else if (a % 7 == 6) {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 4, thang 7";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 9, thang 12";
            }
        } else {
            if (n % 4 != 0) {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 9, thang 12";
            } else {
                out.innerHTML+="thang 6";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but when i use your code then i click the Button, the result is shown in a new page which replaces my current page. Sorry for my trouble, but i need the result shown in below the Submit button.
Many thanks :)

Comment: So kind you are.
Thanks :)